# Two ways to force use of a version of Java for source and target

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, target

For a Maven-based Java project, I have seen two ways to force the use of a specific version of Java in the source and target in a POM file.

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

…and…

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            …
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Why would I use one or the other?

Comment: Its a matter of semantics... see [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Answer (score 2):

it's a matter of taste and preference.  Both - [according to the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) - accomplish essentially the same thing.

The convention I've seen used would be to use the [compiler plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html) instead, since you're given some guarantees about actually forcing a specific version to compile.

Comment: Enforced by what?

Comment: @BasilBourque:  The compiler plugin actively enforces the compiler version.

Comment: By “enforcing”, do you mean overriding other possible IDE settings external to Maven? I suggest expanding your explanation on that point.

Comment: @BasilBourque that's right (see my comment on JavidKhalil's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to use setting menu in your ide. 
For example, in Intelij IDEA you can go File/Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/Compiler/Java compiler and select in rigth panel preferable JDK version. 
Default is, "same as language level".

Comment: Downvoted: if you use maven in the project, these "idea settings" don't matter - maven.compiler.source property value will be used during compiling, or the default value (1.6) if that property is missing. See docs https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/